# Dislash.py Error with Discord Commands 'str' object has no attribute 'type'

Tags: python, google-sheets, discord, discord.py

I am getting an error when using dislash.py with commands in discord. The code is essentially taking data from discord that the user puts in a command and it posts it into a new row in google sheets. The error is below. Does anyone have an idea why this is occurring? Thank you in advance.

[image: error]

Here is my main code for the command:

```
@slash.command(
name="hi", 
description="Complete this command to win",
options=[
    Option(
         "vara",
         description="What is your favorite color", 
         type=OptionType.STRING,
         required=True
    )
],
guild_ids=test_guilds)

async def floor(inter,vara):
    role_names = [role.name for role in inter.author.roles]
    print(role_names)
    if inter.channel.id != 933170181486805042 or "+" not in role_names:
        await inter.reply('You can not perform this command because you are not the winner.') 
    elif inter.channel.id == 933170181486805042:
        global wl
        if "Superstar" in role_names:
            wl='4'
        elif "Winner" in role_names:
            wl='2'
        elif "Loser" in role_names:
            wl='1'
        else:
            wl='0'
        username = inter.author.mention
        user = inter.author.name
        userid = inter.author.id
        insertRow = [user, username, vara, wl]
        sheet.append_row(insertRow, table_range="A1")
        await inter.reply('Thanks, ' + username + '')
        role = discord.utils.get(inter.author.roles, name='+')
        await inter.author.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: Please post your actual code in a text format. It is near impossible to contextualize an image of an error message.

Comment: Hi. I added the main part of my code